# Merging the results of multiple Mongoid criteria into one criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have a list of events during which people have conversations. My aim is to gather all the conversations that occurred during such events.

I tried to query on each event and add them to an array which I then tried to flatten and remove duplicates as so:

```rb
# this works fine
def event_conv_selector(event) 
  user_ids = event.participations.pluck(:user_id)
  users = ::User.in(id:user_ids)
  Conversation.where(:created_at => event.range_for_conversations).in(initiator_profile_id: students.pluck(:id))
end

conversations = []
# RAM can't hold that many conversations, it fails...
Event.each do |event|
  conversations << event_conv_selector(event).to_a
end

conversations.flatten.uniq(&:_id)
```

My question is: Is there a way to query and merge result for all criteria in another criteria that i can handle without ripping my RAM?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you just need unique ids then just hold ids instead of whole objects.

```
require 'set'

def event_conv_selector(event)
  Conversation...pluck(:id) # return id array
end

conversations = Set.new
Event.each do |event|
  conversations.merge(event_conv_selector(event))
end
conversations.to_a
```

or else you can override `eql?` of the Conversation class and only keep the unique objects in the set collection.

your query and relations are not clear to me. however, [check this gem](https://github.com/ElMassimo/mongoid_includes) to improve eager loading of Mongoid, even for nested/polymorphic associations.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is only with conversation objects, you could try:

```
# same as before
def event_conv_selector(event) 
  user_ids = event.participations.pluck(:user_id)
  users = ::User.in(id:user_ids)
  Conversation.where(:created_at => event.range_for_conversations).in(initiator_profile_id: students.pluck(:id))
end

conversation_ids = Set.new
Event.each do |event|
  conversation_ids += event_conv_selector(event).pluck(:id)
end
```